# Can I interact with a windows console program with R

Tags: r, shell

**EDIT: I am working on solving this problem through the Genepop settings file but I am also interested in the general issue of this problem, can I interact with windows console programs with R?**

I would like to automate using a genetic analysis program, [Genepop](http://genepop.curtin.edu.au/), by issueing commands to the windows console from R.  Opening the program is trivial, however I don't know if it is possible to enter the next consecutive lines after opening. The first thing I need to do is enter a text file. If I could pass any small simple character string I would know if I could get a message that would tell me I could it working.

```
> shell(".../Genepop.exe")
Genepop version 4.2.2

Unable to open file genepop.txt
Unable to open file genepop.txt
Genepop version 4.2.2


Name of the data file ? (press ENTER to quit)
>
```

It will quit out if I just open the program without asking for the next line in R. Pretty much what I expected.  I then tried using a semicolon like it mentions in shell help file for the command arguement.

> ... so command
>   can be anything the shell regards as executable, including shell
>   scripts, and it can contain multiple commands separated by ;.

But this didn't seem to help.

```
>first_line <- paste(genepopDir, genepopFile, sep = "/")
>data_file <- "genepopInput"
>test <- paste(first_line,data_file, sep = ";")
>shell(test)
Genepop version 4.2.2

Unable to open file genepop.txt
Unable to open file genepop.txt

Reading settings file cmdline.txt...
Genepop version 4.2.2


Name of the data file ? (press ENTER to quit)
```

So maybe I can use a character vector? There is some documentation under the input argument that is hinting to me that is what I should try.

```
> test <- c(first_line, data_file)
> shell(test)
Error in system(command, as.integer(flag), f, stdout, stderr) : 
  character string expected as first argument
```

I'm using R 3.1, windows 7, x86.

Comment: Do you want to enter something to stdin of external process? Consider [system2](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system2.html) and its *input* argument.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an option to specify the file when running the Genepop program?  You can construct a command line using `paste` or `sprintf` to then pass to `system`.

Your command will probably be something more like:

```
shell( paste( first_line, data_file ) )
```

Another option that may work is to use the `pipe` function to open a pipe to the program, then you can send information to the program using the pipe.  Generally this only works one way, you would need to know exactly what things the program is expecting, in what order, when, etc. and send those strings.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to interactively control a program like that isn't a good idea and luckily it looks like you won't have to deal with that. The Genepop program will also take a settings text file where you can specify all the commands and options you want to run. Then you can run

```
Genepop settingsFile=SampleSettings.txt
```

to run the commands in the file. One of the options is `GenepopInputFile` where you specify the input data file rather than trying to send that to the shell. You can build the settings file dynamically first in R and write that to a file before calling Genepop.

This information came from the [Genepop Documentation](http://kimura.univ-montp2.fr/~rousset/Genepop.pdf). I suggest you read that further to lear the best way to interact with that program.

Comment: I'm working on figuring out the settings file. I forgot to include that and edited the post. Can you tell me why do you think what I'm asking about isn't a good idea? Is it because it will be hard to control when the commands get send?